# MVC5 DropDownListFor not selecting correct value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I realize there are tons of questions on SO about this particular issue, however none of the answers that I've already found are doing quite what I am doing.

**View Model**

```
public FreightDiscountViewModel()
    {
        Sign = new List<SelectListItem>();
        States = new List<SelectListItem>();

        FreightDiscounts = new List<FreightDiscountModel>();

        PopSign();
        PopStates();
    }

    public List<FreightDiscountModel> FreightDiscounts { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Sign { get; set; }

    private void PopSign ()
    {
        Sign.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-", Value = "-" });
        Sign.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "+", Value = "+" });
    }

    private void PopStates ()
    {
        States.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AL", Text = "Alabama" });
        States.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AK", Text = "Alaska" });
        States.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AZ", Text = "Arizona" });
        States.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AR", Text = "Arkansas" });
        States.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "CA", Text  = "California" });
        States.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "CO", Text = "Colorado" }); 
    }
}
```

**View**

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.FreightDiscounts.Count; i++ )
 {
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FreightDiscounts[i].State, Model.States, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
     </tr>
 }
```

I am populating my `FreightDiscounts` list in my view model without issue, and right now for testing, I only have 1 state being returned, Alaska. So the 1 record that being populated in that list has the following info

```
AK, 
US, 
50, 
0, 
+
```

My question is that when the view loads, the state dropdown for the 1 record is set to Alabama (AL), and not Alaska like I would expect. Does anyone see anything obvious I am missing?\

**Edit**

JamieD77's answer fixed my problem. I changed my View to the following.

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FreightDiscounts[i].State, 
                                    new SelectList(Model.DStates, "key", "value", Model.FreightDiscounts[i].State), new { @class = "form-control" })
</td>
```

And I changed my View Model to the following

```
public Dictionary<String, String> DStates { get; set; }

DStates.Add("AL","Alabama" );
DStates.Add("AK","Alaska" );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using a SelectList and setting the selected item when you build the dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FreightDiscounts[i].State, 
    new SelectList(Model.States, "Value", "Text", x.FreightDiscounts[i].State), 
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: This totally fixed it. I'm not really 100% sure why it worked, but after 3 hours of head bashing, I'll take it. Thanks!

Comment: one of the `<options>` in the generated `<select>` needs to have the `selected` attribute if you want it to be selected.  you other option is to set the `Selected` property on the `SelectListItem` like this `States.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AK", Text = "Alaska", Selected = true });` but this would make that selected in all of your dropdowns.. so best to use `new SelectList()` in this case

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909070/html-dropdownlistfor-default-selected-value-in-mvc5/30911222#30911222) explains it in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because your Text and Value fields are reversed?

Edit:  OP has updated his code, they originally were reversed.

Comment: Interesting. I fixed that simple little problem, however the problem remains